# FFmpeg cutting off exceeded time

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

Following ffmpeg command is working fine except it cuts down the exceeded -t duration:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -t 49 -i 1.wav -ss 00:00:05 -t 400 -i 2.wav -ss 00:00:05 -t 49 -i 3.wav -filter_complex "[0:0][1:0][2:0]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1[outa]" -map "[outa]" output.mp3
```

In this example, 2.wav file is 00:05:09 in length, and we are requesting to get next 400 seconds. Time that exceeded, which is 96 seconds in this example is removed from the output file, and my client doesn't want that.

That extra time should be 96 seconds of silence. Does ffmpeg have such capability or will it always remove the extra time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:05 -t 49 -i 1.wav -ss 00:00:05 -t 400 -i 2.wav -ss 00:00:05 -t 49 -i 3.wav
 -filter_complex "[1]apad,atrim=0:400[1a];[0][1a][2]concat=n=3:v=0:a=1" output.mp3
```

The middle file has silent padding added at the end. The trim filter keeps it to 400s duration. The result is then fed  to concat.

`-t 400` as applied to an input means to read that much data from the input. If that amount doesn't exist then, ffmpeg will read as much as available.